# WPF Template.FindName return always null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, findname

Template

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Viewport}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Viewport}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas x:Name="PART_Canvas" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the code in OnApplyTemplate

```
content = this.Template.FindName("PART_Canvas", this) as FrameworkElement;
```

the content returns always null, why it doesn't work?

if I replace with this, the program quits directly

```
content = this.ItemsPanel.FindName("PART_Canvas", this) as FrameworkElement;
```

Comment: In OnApplyTemplate method try something like content = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("PART_Canvas") and see whether it works or not.

Comment: @Sai GetTemplateChild doesn't work..The canvas is in ItemsPanel I don't know how can I access it..

Comment: @sircodesalot `This`, is a custom control derrived from ItemsControl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `FindName` you can find only elements declared in a `Template`. `ItemsPanel` is not part of that template. `ItemsControl` puts `ItemsPanel` into `ItemsPresenter` place holder via which you can access your `Canvas` but first you need to name `ItemsPresenter` in your template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Viewport}">
   <Border>
      <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PART_ItemsPresenter"/>
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

then, using `VisualTreeHelper` get your `Canvas`, but I think earliest place when you can call code below is when `FrameWorkElement` is `Loaded`. This is my example:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
  public MyListBox()
  {
      AddHandler(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ControlIsLoaded));
  }

  private void ControlIsLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      var canvas = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.Template.FindName("PART_ItemsPresenter", this) as DependencyObject, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, in my custom control, the constructor is static so I can't add 'AddHandler' in the constructor, but I put this in 'OnApplyTemplate' it works well. Thank you!